# Split a string into array without empty element

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, split

Attempting to split a string into separated letters

```
String string1 ="KKXGJRNQGA";
List<String> solutionArray = Arrays.asList(string1.split(""));
```

will return `[, K, K, X, G, J, R, N, Q, G, A]` before each alphabet a space and at [0] is an empty element.
But actually i want is `[K,K,X,G,J,R,N,Q,G,A]`, is there a way to solve it? can using regex match?

Answer (score 2):

Using `string1.split("")` will return an empty first value.

Use [toCharArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa989247%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which converts the string to a new character array.

```
"KKXGJRNQGA".toCharArray()
```

or a simple regular expression

```
String s = "KKXGJRNQGA";
String[] p = s.split("(?!^)");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(p));
```

Output:

```
[K, K, X, G, J, R, N, Q, G, A]
```

Comment: I don't understood how this regex works "(?!^)"  what is it mean? how is it works ? please explain thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
char[] letters = string1.toCharArray();
```

Comment: ... and you can change that to a List or to Strings later (or ideally use as is).